# What is the usefulness of the mean file with AlexNet neural network?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, cntk

When using an AlexNet neural network, be it with caffe or CNTK, it needs a mean file as input. What is this mean file for ? How does it affect the training ? How is it generated, only from training sample ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mean subtraction removes the DC component from images. It has the geometric interpretation of centering the cloud of data around the origin along every dimension. It reduces the correlation between images which improves training. From my experience I can say that it improves the training accuracy significantly. It is computed from the training data. Computing mean from the testing data makes no sense.

Comment: Your answer is interesting, but could you expand on how if affects training. Will my model be (a little or a lot) less accurate if I don't use a mean ?

Comment: @rold2007 it will be much harder for your model to converge without subtracting the mean.

Comment: It doesn't remove the DC component!  It would only remove the DC component if you subtract an image that consists of a single color (which happens to be the DC component of that image).